# PHP get, modify and display incoming URL

Tags: php

We are directing all incoming traffic in a directory to a specific page because not all content is ready. Traffic is being redirected to a specific page. It is what it is, and the URL structure aint pretty. I need to get the incoming URL - before the redirect, modify one part of it and display it on the page.

I can get the incoming URL like this
`$incoming_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

which would ouput this: `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4-lang/Page.php`

I need to take that url, and ONLY CHANGE the /dir4-lang/ to /dir4-newLang/ so the URL I display on the page would be `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4-newLang/Page.php`

I think I'm on the right track but need some help with:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$my_var = 'en-en';
$temp = explode( '/'  , $url );
$temp[6] = $my_var;
$url = implode( '/' , $temp );
```

It is close but the incoming URL is http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4-lang/Foo.php and I am outputting

Comment: [implode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: You might better served by adding a rewrite rule to your web server config.

Comment: Yes, thanks I completely spaced that. If you want internet points, answer and I will mark correct. thx for the nudge!

Comment: ShaunUK, this instance I just need to display a modified link, not direct anyone to it

Comment: $url = str_replace("/dir4-lang/", "/en-en/", $url);

Comment: @SheppardDigital, right on man. One item I forgot is I need to remove part of the url before the query string. so if url is ...../Page.php?stuff, I need to remove the 'Page.php' part and just leave the /?stuff inthe outputted url

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
$my_var = 'dir4-newLang';
$temp = explode( '/'  , $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$key = array_search('dir4-lang', $temp);
$temp[$key] = $my_var;
$last = count($temp) - 1;
$temp[$last] = strstr($temp[$last], '?');
echo $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]" . implode( '/' , $temp );
```

So `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4-lang/Page.php?stuff` gonna output `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4-newLang/?stuff`